# I can't get the correct value for the size of my stripline

Tags: c#, .net, charts

I am currently working on a module to create charts to display data.
I use `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart`.

I have two striplines and even though I give them the same value for the `StripWidth` parameter:

Here we have `MaxY` at 6000, average at `2300` and threshold at `2500`

```
// We can't use a fixed size because if the y axis is too high or too small it may look too big or too small
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].Axes[1].StripLines[0].StripWidth = maxY / 100;
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].Axes[1].StripLines[1].StripWidth = maxY / 100;

// add the striplines 
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].Axes[1].StripLines[0].Interval = 0;
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].Axes[1].StripLines[1].Interval = 0;

this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].Axes[1].StripLines[0].IntervalOffset = average;
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].Axes[1].StripLines[1].IntervalOffset = threshold;
```

They often end up with different size, it's subtle but I can see it and I don't understand why it's happening.

[image: example]

Comment: they are the same size to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an **optical illusion**: The screenshot shows two lines with the same width of 3 pixels!

The darker, green one **looks** a little tighter but when you count the pixels you will see they are the same:

[image]

To avoid the effect I suggest giving them a color with the same **brightness**!

Also note that due to rounding you may always get a non-perfect sub-pixel anti-aliasing effect.

**Finally (and most important)**: In the screenshot **the gridline adds to the illusion**. Once again: To avoid this make sure the gridline and the striplines have **more dictinct brightness** values!

Checking in photoshop: In the screenshot you have the first stripline with `brightness=109`, the gridline  `brightness=100`, which is basically the same, so they merge, taking the width from 3 to 4 pixels. But the second stripline has a `brightness=50`. This leads to a perceived extra width of 33% which is noticeable.

Note that the gridline colors can be as easily set as the stripline colors..